# Certificate creation for Apple push notifications

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator, ssl-certificate

I need to integrate apple push notifications. I am not clear about the certificate needed for the server. As I know this is a generated certificate form server end and does it needed to be signed by a valid certificate authority? If so how does APNS going to validate this?

For the apple sandbox cant we proceed with a test certificate?

Is there any chance to test this APNS process in the simulator?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the certificate on the iOS Provisioning Portal, according to the instructions on the docs (also available on the portal). You don't need to worry about the details of the certificate; the Provisioning Portal takes care of all the details for you. You need to do this for each of you App IDs and you need to be the Agent of your organization to do this.

Comment: Thanks Nick. So in addition to that do we need to create the CA certificates? Is so does it need to be signed by a valid certificate authority?

Comment: No, Dilshan, you don't need to do that. The Portal does everything for you.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I am referring to the server certificate. See this link. This is the library I am using for push notifications. http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/source/browse/trunk/sample_server.php                                                    Here there are 2 .pem files. One is for apple certificate and the other one should be the server certificate. Am I correct. Just want to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's what the server wants, but as far as I can tell it's used to verify the receiving end. I have rolled my own server in Objective-C without that additional bit (the Apple-provided certificate was enough to authenticate you to APNS).

Comment: Thanks Nick it really helped me. I was able to successfully configure APNS. Thanks.